# NodeJS 'http' object is supposed to have a method called get() but where is it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, http-request

I would like to see in my console either "Got response" or "Got error".

I've been trying to perform an HTTP request using [http.get()](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.8.15/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) but I get the following error when I try.

```
D:\wamp\www\Chat\server\test.js:19
http.get("http://google.com", function(res) {
     ^
TypeError: Object #<Server> has no method 'get'
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\wamp\www\Chat\server\test.js:19:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

Here is test.js in its entirety:

```
var http = require('http').createServer(handler);

var fs = require('fs');

http.listen(9090);

function handler(req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html', function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(500);
            return res.end('Error loading index.html');
        }

        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
    });
}

http.get("http://google.com", function(res) {
    console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
}).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

Executing `node --version` in cmd returns `v0.8.15`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you're calling `get()` on the server you created, not on the http object:

```
var http = require('http').createServer(handler);
```

your http should be:

```
var http = require('http');
```

then you can use `http.get();`

Answer (score 2):

The `http` module does in fact have a top-level `get` method, but your variable `http` is a reference to an instance of `http.Server` rather than to the module itself. Servers don't have methods for making client requests. Change the first few lines to

```
var http = require('http');

var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(handler).listen(9090);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are asking an httpServer to do get, and not http itself!  The get method will work if you do it like this:

```
var http = require('http');

http.get("http://google.com", function(res) {
    console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
}).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

This does not require creating a server.